# Center and expand widgets inside a scrollable frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this code here:

```
root = Tk() 
    container = Frame(root)
    canvas = Canvas(container, borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness = 0, width=500, height=500, bg = "white")
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    scrollable_frame = Frame(canvas)
    scrollable_frame.bind(
        "<Configure>",
        lambda e: canvas.configure(
            scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
        )
    )

    canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame)

    canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)


    root.geometry("700x600")
    coordF=LabelFrame(scrollable_frame,text='c')
    coordF.pack(side = 'top')
    Label(coordF,text='q',font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 15)).grid(row=0,column=0)
    Label(coordF,text='d:',font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 15)).grid(row=1,column=0)
    v = StringVar(value=None)
    e1=Entry(coordF, textvariable=v)
    e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    e2=Entry(coordF)
    e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
    scalF=LabelFrame(scrollable_frame,text='d')
    scalF.pack()
    e3=Button (scalF, text='f',font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 12),command=random, bg="grey")
    e3.pack(side='top')
    chosenFile = Label(scalF,textvariable=file_result,font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 10), wraplength=300)
    chosenFile.pack(side='top')
    scalOut=LabelFrame(scrollable_frame,text='hg')
    scalOut.pack()

    Label(scalOut,textvariable=xt,font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 12), wraplength=450).pack()
    Label(scalOut,textvariable=frr,font=('Bahnschrift SemiLight', 12), wraplength=450).pack()
    container.pack(expand=True)
    canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both")
    scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
    optF=LabelFrame(root,text="zh")
    optF.pack(side = 'top')  

    

    root.mainloop()
```

The elements that are in the scrollable frame always visualised in the top left part of scrollable frame. I tried grid and pack to make them in the center and expanded but nothing moved. Well, maybe I didn't know where to put my code. Anyway, I want that the widgets centered and expanded one another in the scrollable frame. This may clarify the idea:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the width of `scrollable_frame` to same as that of the canvas by using `canvas.itemconfig()`:

```py
frame_id = canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor='nw')
canvas.itemconfig(frame_id, width=canvas.winfo_reqwidth())
```

And those frames inside `scrollable_frame` will be center horizontally because `.pack(side='top')` is used on them.

It is pointless to expand and center vertically for a vertically scrollable frame.

Comment: thank you!
the centering part worked. However the expanding part didn't. Should I modify other parameters? I am not sure if expand is the right word but what I mean is add spaces vertically between ```coordF``` and ```scalF``` and  ```scalOut``` inside the scrollable frame @acw1668

Comment: For this case, add `pady=20` (adjust the value to suit your requirement) to `.pack(...)` on `coordF`, `scalF` and `scalOut`.